# Ford Fusion 2014 Wiring Diagram

Tags: audio, wiring, fusion, speakers

I just picked up a new 2014 Ford Fusion and am planning on modifying the factory audio equipment. I've been searching around on some websites (The 12 Volt and various forums) and can't seem to find a reliable source for it. I tried buying a service manual and they were either not available or sold out. I don't want to wait for an online order if I don't have to.

Does anyone have a diagram or can point me in the right direction for one? All I really need are the speaker wire colors from behind the radio or if they're in the trunk somewhere, that'd be incredible.

Comment: Before you go and hack your wiring harness, what exactly are you thinking of doing? Just curious.

Comment: I'm keeping the radio stock due to the Sync tools and depth of integration. I have some gear from my old car (Kicker QS65.2 Components for front, Polk Audio 6.5s for rear, 12" Kicker L7 Sub, and Kicker IX1000.5 Amplifier) that I want to bring into this one. The car is base model, so the 4-speaker system that it comes with is sufficient only at lower (>50%) volumes. Any higher and there is a lot of distortion especially in vocals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did some digging and managed to find a PDF of the entire wiring diagram for the 2014. I'll post a OneDrive link below for anyone who wants to download them. They also contain dashboard disassembly instructions and whatnot.

Amp Location: Right side of trunk. If you have the amp, it seems that the speaker wires are the same colors there as in the front of the vehicle.

Constant 12V (Radio) => white/brown
Radio Ignition => HS CAN
Radio Illumination => HS CAN
Amp Turn On => Purple/Red
Power Antenna => green/purple

FR Speaker + => White/violet stripe 
FR Speaker - => White/orange stripe

FL Speaker + => White
FL Speaker - => White/brown stripe

RR Speaker + => Brown/white stripe
RR Speaker - => Brown/blue stripe

RL Speaker + => White/green stripe
RL Speaker - => Brown/yellow stripe

FL Tweeter + => Grey/orange stripe
FL Tweeter - => Green/orange stripe

FR Tweeter + => Violet/orange stripe
FR Tweeter - => Yellow/orange stripe

Front Center Speaker + => Green
Front Center Speaker - => Grey/yellow stripe

Rear Center Speaker + => Green/brown stripe
Rear Center Speaker - => Violet/brown stripe

Left Subwoofer + => Green/purple stripe
Left Subwoofer - => Gray

Right Subwoofer + => Purple
Right Subwoofer - => Yellow

http://1drv.ms/1lMkryJ 
This is the link to the PDF that I'm referencing.

Answer (score 2):

Most manufacturers tend to be fairly consistent with their stereo wiring, so it ought to be the same as other modern Fords. A quick googling reveals [This site](http://www.carstereo.com/help/carwires.cfm), which suggests the following:

`Power
Memory (+12v Constant)      Green Yellow
Ignition (+12v Switched)    Yellow/Black
Ground (-)                  Black or Fat Red
Illumination                Orange
Dimmer                      Orange/White
Power Antenna               Blue (varies greatly)`

`Speakers
Right Front (+)     White/Green
Right Front (-)     Green/Orange
Left Front (+)      Orange/Green
Left Front (-)      Light Blue
Right Rear (+)      Pink/Blue
Right Rear (-)      Green/orange
Left Rear (+)       Pink/green
Left Rear (-)       Pink/Blue`

With, of course, the usual disclaimers...

Comment: Awesome. I'm surprised that I didn't see this earlier. If I don't find an exact diagram, this will definitely help. The only thing I'm concerned about is that I did read on The12Volt that the car has a data cable in the harness as of 2013+ so I am a bit nervous about tapping into unknown territory. Regardless, if I use this and it is correct, I'll come back and mark it as the answer for sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you pop off the trim and look at the wires, the two twisted together will be for the speakers. The power locks and windows will all run straight. Twisting speaker wires together helps with interference noise and is done on ford's. From factory.