# Looking for 2013 Ford Fusion Stereo wiring diagram - SONY system

Tags: audio, fusion, diagram

I'm looking for the wiring diagram for a 2013 Ford Fusion with the SONY system.

I am having a problem with my front left woofer, in that it sometimes it cuts out. Sometimes when it does finally cut back in, it is distorted. It does seem that when it is below freezing is when both the cutting out/distortionn occurs. Trying to determine if it's the speaker, wiring, or the amp/dsp. My first order of business will be swapping the front woofers to see if the problem switches sides.

Any thoughts on the above would be helpful as well :)

Comment: It sounds like you have loose connection. Your first order of business is to find all the end-point connections (behind the speaker and at the amp) and check for good connections.  Then you'll need to start following wires to see if they're rubbing somewhere.  A wiring diagram will help you see how the system works and all its parts, but it you'll be unlikely to find where the wires actually are in the car from a drawing.

Comment: Thanks, I have already disconnected/reconnected the wiring at the amp. Since it is only the woofer and not the tweeter on that side, I think I can rule out the radio/wiring from radio to amp. Because I am almost 100% certain he audio in is a single channel and the amp is also the dsp that acts as the crossover between the woofer and tweeter.

When I take the door panels off, I will play with the connection at that end, and also test the voltage & ohms at both ends. which is why I wanted the diagram as well to know what is what.

Comment: Sounds like you have a good plan!  Does [this](http://www.focusst.org/forum/focus-st-electronics/3883-2013-focus-st-sony-amp-wiring-diagram.html) seem correct (like colors, number of speakers, etc)?  Also, have you seen [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12061/ford-fusion-2014-wiring-diagram) question?

Comment: I am a former DIY'er with Car Audio, so I know the troubleshooting process with signals :) Biggest problem with OEM is dealing with the oem wiring/harnesses (and not being able to flip the patchcords to test that end of things. I did come across the Focus' wiring diagram. The biggest difference is that it doesn't seem the Focus has the center speaker on the front dash, so it may or may not align with the wiring of my car. I also did see that other post, unfortunately the one drive link no longer works :(

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to find a diagram of the 14 Fusion/MKZ and it's for the base system all the up through the SONY in the Titanium and the THX system available in the Lincoln.  Here is the link for anyone who may want it in the future (and hopefully it doesn't die on anyone before they can use it!

[2014 Fusion Audio Wiring Diagram](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32767348/2014%20Fusion%20Radio%20wiring.pdf)